# extracting install iso to a partion

Tags: installation, boot, grub2, partitioning

I currently have ubuntu 12.04 installed and I am ready to upgrade. I would like to do a "clean install" for various reasons. When I installed 12.04 I had extracted the iso to a 1GB "installer" partion on my hard disk and I would like to do the same thing now, but I can no longer find instructions on how to do this. I thought I could use the usb creator tools (either usb-creator-gtk or unetbootin) but it seems neither of these will write the install files to a local partion. I honestly can't remember but I may have used dd to write the image to the partition but given the low-level nature of what's going on I'd like to ask before typing these things in the terminal. I believe I can do it as follows

```
dd bs=4096 if=/home/user/downloads/ubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64.iso of=/dev/sda6 conv=notrunc,noerror
```

I have verified that sda6 is in fact the partition I wish to extract to by looking at the drive labels in gparted.

I like having the installer iso on a partition that grub can find so that when I run into problems I always have a "spare" system on hand that I can boot into and mess around with config files. However I hate having to burn isos to dvd or dig through my ten cheapo usb sticks to find the one that actually works with a bootloader on it. I also like the fact that `update-grub` can find that partition and add it to the boot menu, so that if I do something to make my main system unbootable I just down-arrow to the installer menu item from grub and have a nice desktop from which I can fix things, or, in the worst case, just start over with a clean install (/home is a separate partition, so I dont really lose anything this way).

So my question, is basically just: is this the right command?

Answer (score 3):

If you have grub on your hard drive or on a flash drive, you can directly boot the ISO using grub2's loopmount. Works for Ubuntu desktop and many other Linux but not all ISO.

I used to copy ISO to flash drive and boot ISO as then I can have more than one (several repair type Linux ISO) on my somewhat larger 4GB flash drives. But I also have the install ISO on my hard drive.

This will boot an ISO from a hard drive.
ISO Booting with Grub 2 from Hard drive - drs305

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot

Examples - you may copy & edit for your path & ISO version

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot/Examples

If you have multiple drives or a flash drive, numbering of drive can be an issue. The drive you boot from is always hd0 in grub. Then they may be numbered in port order or how BIOS loads drives.

I also have nVidia and have to add nomodeset boot parameter to get an ISO to boot. Some versions of Ubuntu use vmlinuz.efi even if not UEFI booting and others just use vmlinuz. I just recently copied my Ubuntu boot stanza to boot Xubuntu and Ubuntu had the .efi and Xubuntu did not and it took me a couple of tries and opening ISO to see what it used to realize the difference.